# Angular 4: base href with a filename

Tags: angular

My application is loaded inside another non-Angular application at a specific URL with a path+filename.

I want to use Angular's ActivatedRoute to set and read URL parameters. (For now there are no actual routes and I don't use router-outlet.)

My app.module.ts has this code:

```
imports: [
  RouterModule.forRoot([], { initialNavigation: false })
],
providers: [
  { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/path/filename.html' }
]
```

This is working, but when i set URL parameters I get an unwanted extra slash behind the base href.

```
this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: { foo: 'bar' } });
```

The above code results in: /path/filename.html/?foo=bar instead of /path/filename.html?foo=bar

Comment: why can't you just name the index document index.html?

Comment: It's not an actual file but a CMS system that pretends to be an HTML file. Which is completely out of my control.